# how to stop gridpane items shrink with shrinking of window in java fx 2.0

Tags: java, javafx-2, gridpanel

Hello i have that grid pane and there is labels and textboxes in that they are shrinking with shrinking the window but table view is not shrinking. Like rather than shrinking they hide like normal.Is any method to stop that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you post a sketch of your layout, or even a piece of code that we can compile to see the problem?

Comment: i tried to put my screenshot here but i dont have that much reputation here i guess :D lol

Comment: Put it somewhere else and post a link.

Comment: [link]http://tinypic.com/r/idxc35/6

Comment: I have attached the pic above in the grid i have set the labels and textbox but when iam resizing the screen its got shrinking.. Thanks

Comment: Set the minWidth property of your "Customer Details" gridpane. Or set the minWidth of the labels and textboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the minWidth property works :)

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about your UI, I can only give a general answer:

To influence the shrink/growth behaviour of components in JavaFX, you have to [stack the various simple panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/layout/builtin_layouts.htm#CHDGHCDG) that come with JavaFX into each other, or use a more powerful pane, like [MiG Layout for FX 2](http://www.miglayout.com/).